# How can I make a QCheckBox for (un)checking several QCheckBoxes?

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox

I am writing a subclass of `QCheckBox` that I would like to display to the user for checking or unchecking a set of existing check boxes. It works by reacting on the `toggled(bool)` signals of the check boxes.

The "master" check box must be a tristate check box. When some of the "slave" check boxes are checked but not all of them, the master is set to `Qt::CheckState::PartiallyChecked`.

It doesn't work well enough. Although I want to set the master check box to "partially checked" within my code, the user should not be able to do that. Clicking onto the master check box should completely check all check boxes except if all of them are already checked. In that case it should uncheck them all. Yet, my master check box also switches to the intermediate state when I click onto it.

I guess that I can change that by overriding `void QAbstractButton::checkStateSet()` and `void QAbstractButton::nextCheckState()`, but I do not understand the documentation of these methods. What should they do? And how can I override them to get the expected behaviour?

Comment: Override only nextCheckState(), returning Checked if it is Unchecked and Unchecked if it is Checked (and Checked or Uchecked if it is Partially checked). Never return PartiallyChecked :)

Comment: @Fabio Great. But instead of "returning" you probably meant "setting check state", since the method has no return value. It works now. Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: You are right! I have posted am answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nextCheckState()` method is called when the check box is clicked to change the check state.

You can ovverride the `QCheckBox::nextCheckState()` method to set the new check state depending on the current check state.

Example:

```
void MyCheckBox::nextCheckState()
{
    if(checkState() == Qt::Checked)
        setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    else
        setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
}
```

In this way, the `Qt::PartiallyChecked` state is never set when the user click the check box.